# Load XML as an Annotation for Stanford CoreNLP?

Tags: stanford-nlp

There is lots of information on taking an Annotation and saving it to XML.  Is it possible to deserialize, i.e. load the XML into an Annotation?  For example, my use case is: I want to do cheap preprocessing like sentence splitting, then later decide to do more expensive parsing, and I'd like the original document text offsets to be correctly preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: John Bauer
Date: Wed, Mar 13, 2013 at 1:52 AM
Subject: Re: [java-nlp-user] Can XML be deserialized into CoreMap etc. structures?
To: Brendan O'Connor
Cc: "java-nlp-user@lists.stanford.edu" 


No, there is no code to deserialize the XML output.
We're always interested in user extensions, though :)

John
```